# MultiBit Classic wallet gone

Tags: multibit

I formated my computer yesterday, and my MultiBit Classic wallets are gone. I just tried a trial software to recover the files, and they appeared as found. But I cannot recover unless I buy the full version.

The wallets didn't ask for any password when I open MultiBit. If I successfully recover the .wallet files, I will be able to recover my bitcoins with this files only? I dont remember to configure any passwords or anything for this wallets. The only data that I can recover is the .wallets file. Is this enough?

Answer (score 5):

Yes your wallet file will be sufficient to recover your Bitcoin if you did not encrypt it with a password.

In the future please encrypt your wallet and store backups offline